# Is it possible to change the background color of text highlighted while using a code template in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In other words, when you type `for` and hit ctrl+space, you can pick various template `for` loops. After selecting, it creates the code and lets you tab between various aspects of the code (such as which array you're looping over). I've switched to dark colors on Eclipse, but I can't find anywhere to change the highlight for these tab areas, so they show up with light backgrounds and my light foreground colors and are completely unreadable.

Is it possible to change these colors somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time, but I found it.

Look under window>Preferences>General>Text Editors>Linked Mode

Then it is "Editable Range" you are looking for.

In preferences:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't find a prefs setting by searching for "color", there probably is no way to do this. I suggest to open a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/